# Format number as phone in text box when onBlur

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm terrible at JS regular expressions and I'm counting on an intelligent being to help me accomplish what should be a trivial task.

Onblur, I want a text field of 10 numbers '1234567890' to be formatted as 123/456/7890 using JS.

And Onfocus, it should revert to the number '1234567890' without slashes.

That's it. Hope you can help!

Update: I arrived at a solution, so I'll post the answer below for the sake of future searchers.

HTML:

```
<input id="PhoneNumber" type="text" maxlength="10"
       onblur="PhoneNumberOnBlur(this)"
       onfocus="PhoneNumberOnFocus(this)"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function PhoneNumberOnBlur(el) { el.value = el.value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1/$2/$3"); }

function PhoneNumberOnFocus(el) { el.value = el.value.replace(/\//g, "") }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if showed what you have tried so far. As stated, it seems as if you are asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add slashes:

```
var num = "1234567890"
num.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1/$2/$3")
```

to remove them:

```
num.replace(/\//g, "")
```

For something more robust, I'd recommend the Masked Input plugin:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I am not getting this to work. I put it in a function and ran the function onblur. No formatting is added.

Comment: what does this mean ""$1/$2/$3""?